# Is there a way to attach an event in a XAML style?

Tags: events, xaml, styles

I want every clickable TreeViewItem to execute `TreeViewItem_MouseLeftButtonDown`, is there a way to put this in the style so I don't have to define it everywhere. I could run through all children in code behind but I would think there would be an easier way to do it in a style.

The following code gives me:

> Cannot find the Style Property
>   'PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown' on the
>   type
>   'System.Windows.Controls.TreeViewItem'.

```
<Window x:Class="TestClickTree2343.Window1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen"
    Title="Window1" Height="300" Width="300">
    <Window.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="TreeViewItem">
            <Setter Property="IsExpanded" Value="True" />
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#aaa" />
        </Style>
        <Style x:Key="TreeViewItemClickableStyle" TargetType="TreeViewItem">
            <Setter Property="Cursor" Value="Hand" />
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#000" />
            <Setter Property="PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown" Value="TreeViewItem_MouseLeftButtonDown" />
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>

    <StackPanel>
        <TreeViewItem Header="Files">
            <TreeViewItem Header="File 1">
                <TreeViewItem Header="Part 1">
                    <TreeViewItem Style="{StaticResource TreeViewItemClickableStyle}" Header="Paragraph 1"/>
                    <TreeViewItem Header="Paragraph 2"/>
                </TreeViewItem>
            </TreeViewItem>
        </TreeViewItem>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

Comment: Whatever you're trying to do, you're probably going about it the wrong way.  This has a very Winforms smell about it.

Comment: All I want to do is respond to clicks on items in the treeview.

Comment: I'd change the template, stick in a (styled) button and attach a command to it.  But if you're not doing MVVM this might be a bit hard to do...

Comment: ok, I'm now trying: <TreeView SelectedItemChanged="TreeView_SelectedItemChanged">

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use SelectedItemChanged in TreeView instead:

**XAML:**

```
<TreeView  SelectedItemChanged="TreeView_SelectedItemChanged" BorderThickness="0">
    <TreeViewItem 
        Tag="File1" 
        Style="{StaticResource TreeViewItemClickableStyle}" 
        Header="File 1">

        <TreeViewItem Header="Part 1">

            <TreeViewItem Header="Paragraph 1"/>

            <TreeViewItem 
                Tag="Paragraph1" 
                Style="{StaticResource TreeViewItemClickableStyle}" 
                Header="Paragraph 2"/>

            <TreeViewItem Header="Paragraph 3"/>
            <TreeViewItem Header="Paragraph 4"/>
            <TreeViewItem Header="Paragraph 5"/>

        </TreeViewItem>
    </TreeViewItem>
</TreeView>
```

**Code-behind:**

```
private void TreeView_SelectedItemChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<object> e)
{
    TreeViewItem treeViewItem = ((TreeView)sender).SelectedItem as TreeViewItem;
    if (treeViewItem.Tag != null)
    {
        string tag = treeViewItem.Tag.ToString();
        MessageBox.Show(String.Format("You clicked the tree item: {0}", tag));
    }
}
```